# How to add multiple omnidirectional microphones to a computer

Tags: microphone, microphone-positioning, multiple

What is the easiest way to connect multiple omnidirectional microphones to a computer that is used in a large conference room? For example, I cannot find a USB connected device with the ability to connect multiple microphones that are placed on different ends of a long conference table. Having only 1 mic in the middle of the table is not close enough to everyone around the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

- a digital mix console, such as:

  - [Alesis MultiMix 8/16 USB](http://www.alesis.com/multimix16usb20),
    [image]
- a big audio interface, such as:

  - [Presonus AudioBox 1818VSL USB](https://www.presonus.com/products/AudioBox-1818VSL),
    [image]
  - [Tascam US-16x8](http://tascam.com/product/us-16x08/),
    [image]
  - [Focusrite Scarlett 18i8](http://us.focusrite.com/usb-audio-interfaces/scarlett-18i8)
    [image]

Comment: Thanks, this helps confirm that I'll have to go down this road.